# No Multi-Threading with R on Linux

Tags: linux, cpu, r, scheduling

I'm doing a statistical analysis using R on Ubuntu 15.10 operating system. My R script takes a very long time to complete. About 2 - 3 hours.

Meanwhile I've checked my CPUs load. I just noticed that all CPUs are almost idle but one. In the picture below, as you can see only CPU 8 is at 100%.

[image]

Why doesn't Linux kernel balance workload on all CPUs?

Comment: http://www.glennklockwood.com/data-intensive/r/parallel-options.html

Comment: sounds like your R script is written to be single-threaded. It is important that the programmer determine and define what degree of parallelism their application has, to avoid the many pitfalls of parallel programming, so no OS will just run bits of a process on whatever processing facility is free. the program must be written to account for what bits can be run seperately.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10835122/1856738

Comment: @FrankThomas Seems R scripts can't be written in multi-threaded nature. So, is there any workaround to speed up my analysis?

Comment: @HiI'mfrogatto, you are mistaken. The link that choroba already posted shows how to write multi-threaded R scripts.

Comment: @ChrisInEdmonton Okay, I'll check out.

Comment: @HiI'mfrogatto, it looks like you have found documentation on How to multithread. The bigger and somewhat more complex problem is going to be determining whether your algorithm can be made asynchronous, with little bits of your calculations occuring independently, but in a way that the results can be coordinated. This is not simple stuff, and we can't really help you with it. I would recommend posting on StackOverflow if you have further questions about how to implement a parallel algorithm for your needs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Linux does balance workload across all CPUs. However, in order to do so, the workload must be multithreaded. It's not possible to distribute a single-threaded workload across multiple CPUs and indeed, it's most efficient to keep a single-threaded task on a single CPU.

The problem here is that the R script in question wasn't written to be multi-threaded.

Answer (score 0):

If your process yields to mapReduce, you can split the script into pieces and run each piece on a different CPU.

Answer (score -1):

It is not `kernel` who decide how to use `CPU`. If your'e script is designed to be multi-threaded  then only it will use other threads.